# Create New Folder without Ribbon Access

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, branding

I am using SharePoint Foundation. In my branding of a document library, I have stripped out everything except for the list. Because of this there is no way to add a new folder correct?

Any ideas on how I could approach this? I'd like to be able to create new folders without including the ribbon, is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can type the url directly for lists folder :

https://abc.com/Lists/ListName/NewForm.aspx?RootFolder=RootListName&Type=1&IsDlg=1

Type below url for Document Library folder:

https://abc.com/DocumentlibraryName/Forms/Upload.aspx?RootFolder=%2fDocumentLibraryName&Type=1&IsDlg=1